# My app crashes when switch back and forth activitys (Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundle

My Activity 2 goes to Activity 3, and my Activity 3 has a Button which allows it to go back to Activity 2. But once I go backwards to Activity 2 and try to go to Activity 3 again, this is when the app crashes.

So Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 2 -> Crashes when going back to Activity 3.

Here is the intent sending me to Activity 3.

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Results1.this, UsersAnswers1.class);
        intent.putExtra("usersAnswers1", usersAnswers1);
        intent.putExtra("isATOF1", isATOF1);

       intent.putExtras(extras); // NullPointerException

        startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the Activity 3 sending me back to Activity 2

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.testResultsButton) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UsersAnswers1.this, Results1.class));
            }
```

I am told I get a NullPointerException on this line right here
in my Activity 2

```
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you get back to activity 2 from activity 3 and you `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` you get `null` since the extras you're receiving are from activity 3 not activity 1. That is because this time you started the activity 2 from the activity 3 and did not put any extras to your intent. getIntent() returns the intent that was used to launch this activity `new Intent(UsersAnswers1.this, Results1.class)` which has no extras.

Comment: @ George D Thank for the  reply, but i'm new to programming. How would I fix this? I'm sorry if I missed it in your answer.

Comment: There are many ways to fix this. Where is your code sending you to the 3 activity in the first place? What method contains all the above? (including the line that throws a `Null Pointer Exception`?

Comment: I posted the code in my op where I am send being sent to the 3rd activity. The method is onButton1Click for both Activities.

Comment: One possible workaround for your problem is to check which `Activity` is your user coming from. If it's the first one you have no problem, if it's the second one you will **not** use the `intent.putExtras(extras);` for that will cause the NPE. Use the getCallingActivity() method in order to figure out which activity launched the activity 2. Then implement an `if else` that goes `if the activity that called activity 2 was the activity 1 proceed as normal, else proceed without `intent.putExtras(extras);`